# Docker private registry Verifying Checksum problem

Tags: docker, ssh, checksum, docker-registry

I try to pull the image from my private registry.

```
docker pull registry.docker.xxxx.si/x/xxx-stage:latest
```

I get

```
latest: Pulling from x/xxx-stage
c5e155d5a1d1: Pull complete 
221d80d00ae9: Pull complete 
4250b3117dca: Pull complete 
3b7ca19181b2: Pull complete 
425d7b2a5bcc: Downloading [==================>                                ]  78.09MB/215.1MB
d7a526a3eca5: Download complete 
73a96b82cd2c: Download complete 
63e5b6830bb3: Download complete 
811d2b8ea37b: Download complete 
7ce10021cecc: Downloading [===================================>               ]  33.02MB/46.23MB
3c23c5f29689: Verifying Checksum 
80f45b14e5bb: Waiting 
faeb4a77afa0: Waiting 
7ec8132694f8: Waiting 
c5c34f90b8d5: Waiting 
a4c305f5572f: Waiting 
d205b39c491d: Waiting 
7ea703accff3: Waiting 
35a9f1a54684: Waiting 
filesystem layer verification failed for digest sha256:3c23c5f29689a71b0fa9a822771604e1e52b1db989248c773171e104d42c165e
```

But this is only from one machine,... if I try the same on other machine it works

### EDIT:

I figure out that on this machine I can't pull any images form registry. 
It always return the same error.

What is going on?

Comment: Do you use VirtualBox?

Comment: No, why do you ask

Comment: Found an issue on github similar to yours . but the reason was VMware bug.

Comment: @MarkoZadravec did you end up solving this problem?

Comment: Continuing to solve the same issue after Marko; the error seems really to be related to VM, will check provisioning cfg (network, storage).